# Searching in Firebase Null with onClick Listener

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, nullpointerexception

I am trying to search for the information in my firebase db, and I am not able to do so.

This is the class in which I'm searching from:

```
private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DjProfile, ResultsViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter;
    public static Query query;

    public static String searchData;
    DatabaseReference mProfileDatabase;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_attendee_landing);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        final RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.results_recycler);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        final EditText t = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.DjNameET);

        mProfileDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        t.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if(i == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH)
                {
                    searchData = t.getText().toString();


                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        ImageButton imgB= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.searchBtn);

        imgB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
               query = mProfileDatabase.orderByChild("djprofile")
                        .startAt(searchData)
                        .endAt(searchData + "\uf8ff");


            }
        });
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<DjProfile> firebaseRecyclerOptions = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<DjProfile>()
                .setQuery(query, DjProfile.class)
                .build();
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DjProfile, ResultsViewHolder>(firebaseRecyclerOptions)
        {

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public ResultsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.searchitem_list, viewGroup, false);

                return new ResultsViewHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ResultsViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull DjProfile model) {
                holder.setDjProfile(model);
            }
        };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
    }
```

[image]

Here is the exception I am getting: (says to be occuring in the onStart() method)

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener com.google.firebase.database.Query.addChildEventListener(com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener)' on a null object reference

Any help as to why this is null would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The value of `query` is null and throw this exception. According to the source code, the query is only assigned after the `imgB` is clicked.

Comment: I understand that. But I want to be able to search for something in that query once that ImageButton is clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to initialize the adapter, you need to have a valid query. And to be able to create the query, you need to have the `searchData`. This means that the initialization of the `firebaseRecyclerAdapter` should happen inside the `onClick`.

```
imgB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
       query = mProfileDatabase.orderByChild("djprofile")
                .startAt(searchData)
                .endAt(searchData + "\uf8ff");

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<DjProfile> firebaseRecyclerOptions = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<DjProfile>()
                .setQuery(query, DjProfile.class)
                .build();
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DjProfile, ResultsViewHolder>(firebaseRecyclerOptions)
        {

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public ResultsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.searchitem_list, viewGroup, false);

                return new ResultsViewHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ResultsViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull DjProfile model) {
                holder.setDjProfile(model);
            }
        };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }
});
```

Comment: I am now getting a NullPointerException in my onStart() method when I tell the activity to start listening to the firebaseRecyclerAdapter

Comment: Well yes, that would make sense if you call `startListening` on an adapter that hasn't been created yet. You should probably move that call to the end of the `onClick`.

Comment: Yeah I've fixed it :)